# How can i change Language URL in Angular

Tags: angular

On a dropdown list with 2 languages, I know how to do it the switch, there are several tutoriels.

However, I am stuck when in my homepage I have to click on a url for example `NL` in the header. I don't know how to do the switch language?

[image]

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

/* */
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

/* */
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.addLangs(['en', 'nl']);
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  }

  switchLang(lang: string) {
    this.translate.use(lang);
  }
}
```

My problem is in my **app.component.html**

I would like to know now how to do the switch language for this code HTML below.

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="languages-right">
    <a href="#">EN </a>
    <a href="#"> | NL </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code for information:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="languages-right">
    <a href="#">EN </a>
    <a href="#"> | NL </a>
  </div>
</div>

<span class="form-inline">
  <select 
      class="form-control" 
      #selectedLang 
      (change)="switchLang(selectedLang.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let language of translate.getLangs()" 
      [value]="language"
      [selected]="language === translate.currentLang">
      {{ language }}
    </option>
  </select>
</span>



<div class="firstText">
  {{'Sitetitle' | translate }}
</div>

<div class="secondText">
  {{'Name' | translate }}
</div>
```

I would like to know how to work ?

Here is an idea of code on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xxvjer?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Thank you a lot for your explanations and your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the `click` event (you may or may not need to handle `event.preventDefault`).

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="languages-right">
    <a href="#" (click)="switchLang('en')">EN</a>
    <span> | </span>
    <a href="#" (click)="switchLang('nl')">NL</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem - one thing I will add is please do not use `<a>` tags like this, use a custom button with no styling.